# Where is the Catel Analytics class?

Tags: catel

I'm trying to use Catel auditing using the [auditor example](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/CTL/pages/1409062/Auditing). However, it calls for the `Analytics` class, which isn't present. Where do I find this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code has been moved to [Orc.Analytics](https://github.com/wildgums/orc.analytics).

Comment: I think it was only an example and never actually part of Catel? Besides that, the Confluence documentation is there for backwards reference only (4.x), the new documentation for Catel can be found at https://docs.catelproject.com

Comment: Thanks. The Catel 5.12 doc link is broken. 5.11 works though.